# Submit python script to Sun Grid Engine with Joblib parallelization

Tags: python, bash, parallel-processing, sungridengine

I have a python script which uses `joblib` module with `loky` backend for parallelization and `n_jobs` is set to `12`. I'm wondering how should I submit it to the sun grid engine with `qsub` command.

I have something like this:

```
qsub -q all.q     \
     -l h_vmem=14G \
     -V             \
     -N              \
     -pe all.pe       \
      12               \
      script.py
```

Would that work as expected for python script with `joblib` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Q** : *"Would that work **as expected** for python script with **`joblib`** module?"*

That heck depends on what one expects from an ***"as expected"*** clause, doesn't that?

The Python-interpreter, as described above, will for sure instantiate **`12`** `n_jobs`-controlled amounts of self-"copied" process-instances ( performed as *`loky`* was implemented ), because it was instructed to do so.

Yet, the **`qsub`** has requested the SGE/SoGE/*GE to pre-configure the GE so as to operate next **`12`** parallel-environment instances ( i.e. fully independently running **`12`** python processes, each having **`14 [GB] RAM`** allocations requirement **`~ 168 [GB] RAM`** - so hope, you have at least that amount of physical RAM-resources, otherwise a nasty swap-thrashing starts, to the devastatingly adverse effects to any expectations one may have from the `joblib` ( to only come later ) tricks.

Each one such Python process, inside its own SGE/SoGE `PARALLEL_ENVIRONMENT` will later start it's own **`12`** *`loky`*-mechanised **`joblib`**-dictated **`n_jobs`**, resulting in **`144`** in total. The nature of their workload will determine, if these become "wasted", if disk-I/O-bound, "underperforming", if the lumpsum of the CPU/RAM-traffic has already headbanged into the physical RAM-I/O-bound ceiling, or "smart", if resources and requirements obey the Lege Artis balance throughout running the whole computing-graph ( for which my hat would be, indeed, raised in respect ).

### The Best [Next Step](https://arc.liv.ac.uk/SGE/htmlman/htmlman1/submit.html) :

Revise the [configuration](https://arc.liv.ac.uk/SGE/htmlman/manuals.html) with your SGE/SoGE Technical Support department, best using a pre-testing run before the main job-submission, with adding **`-v`** "Verifier" :

```
######################################################
#               this-JOB-SUBMISSION-CONFIGURATION-file
######################################################
# Usage:
#
#        gsub @<this-JOB-SUBMISSION-CONFIGURATION-file>
#
# Remarks:
#
#        qsub -q all.q     \      ### -q  define-LIST-OF-QUEUES 2B used 4scheduling this JOB
#             -l h_vmem=14G \     ### -l  define-RESOURCES
#             -V             \    ### -V  export-ALL-ENVIRONMENT-VARS to the job-CONTEXT
#             -N              \   ### -N  qsub-JOB-NAME ? a missing value :: rather test with adding -v qsub-JOB-SUBMISSION-VERIFIER
#             -pe all.pe 12    \  ### -pe instantiate-PARALLEL-ENVIRONMENTS <pe_name> <pe_min>[-][ <pe_max> ]
#              script.py          ###     <command> [ <command_parameters> [...]]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I'm just a bit confused about why there would be 144 processes in total?

Comment: @Wz.X So let's count together ( Each of the **`12 PE`**-s has ( 1 python `(self)` **`+ 12 n_jobs`** ) ) that totals to those initially `qsub`-ed ~ 12 autonomous python processes ( where no one of 'em knows anything about any other of the rest 11 ones ) **+ their "child"-processes `~ +144`** of those, that their `n_jobs`-directed *`loky`*-instantiation was due to copy and operate via **`joblib`**-tools "from inside" of each of those 12 PE's python processes. Report their actual PID and PPID numbers, if still in doubts.